# SAS Send an email via browser

Tags: email, sas

I have a PC where I have only email access through webbrowser firefox or IE. This is due to security (!?) reasons. Is it possible to use the SAS programm and going via browser?

```
%macro sendmail(email);
FILENAME outmail EMAIL  &email
SUBJECT="Report November 2013"
ATTACH= ("&path\stats_&id..pdf");

DATA _NULL_;
FILE outmail;

put 'Dear x';
put 'Blablabla.';
put 'Cheers';
put 'giordano';
RUN;
%mend sendmail;
```

&path and &id are defined somewhere else. The address where I want to send through looks like https://outlook.xyz.co and it asks for my login and a password.
I'm looking for something like

```
FILENAME outmail EMAIL  &email
WEB https://outlook.xyz.co
LOGIN giordano
PASSWORD xxxx;
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.
giordano

Comment: `filename email` is going to work if you can send mail through SMTP, but if you have security limitations, it likely won't work for you in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible within SAS and you know how to do this using another language, you can output a text file from SAS and use [`%sysexec`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000171045.htm) to call a program (which will use the text file).

Comment: @kungujam Thanks for this advice. I think that I have to solve this problem as you said.